# Look up a list embedded in a Google Sheets from a Google Forms, and add attributes to the corresponding row?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'm running an event for a large number of children and need a way to let them register quickly as they come in, to the event.

We're expecting about 400 kids who have pre-enrolled and we will have a list of their names on a Google Sheets.

Some volunteers will be at the entrance with iPads to register the kids. I am hoping to have a Google Forms that can look-up a name on the Google Sheets to ensure that the kid has in fact registered (I can do this), and then enter some additional values in the same row in the Google Sheets (Team Colour, Meal Choice)

So the Google Sheets will have 4 columns: Full Name, Attendance, Team Colour, Meal Choice

To start with, the Full Name column will be prefilled in the google sheets, and the other 3 columns will be left empty. As kids register, I'm hoping to fill the other 3 columns depending on which name we look-up in the Google Forms on a dropdown.

Is this possible?

(I'm aware that I can do this via collaborating on a Google Sheets but wanted to prevent erroneous deletions by having a few people simultaneously editing the sheet directly)

Answer (score -1):

- let's say your form is: **https://forms.gle/7TrRqt8V4Uc7FBTa9**
- and **Sheet1** is pre-populated like:

  [image: pi]
- then paste this into **C1** cell on **Form Responses 1** sheet:

  ```
  ={"Attendance", "Team Colour", "Meal Choice";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet1!A:D, {2,3,4}, 0)))}
  ```

  [image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZXLHq1Uj3l9E5oIvP4irFzZRwwi_6xkthESR6oU5Lyo/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I need to be able to input the Attendance , Team Colour and Meal choice columns on the day via the google forms. I do not have that information prior to them registering. The only pre filled column would be their name and the rest would be empty. Is that possible?

Comment: are you actually asking if you can feed Form' drop-down directly from Sheet so you would not need to populate Form's drop-down manually with 400 kids? if so, that is not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: I see, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: the proper course of action would be to give up on Form and have Google sheet per each of the staff member (to avoid edit collisions) and then have one master spreadsheet on which will merge all datasets from sub sheets